# Using Ruby 1.9.1, how could I access this string's characters one at a time?

Tags: unicode, encoding, ruby-1.9

Let me start by giving you [List of Greek words with English derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_words_with_English_derivatives). Look at the `a` table, first column. Notice there are words like `ἄβαξ`.

Using Ruby 1.9.1, which has better encoding support than Ruby 1.8, how could I iterate over each character forming that word? For example, I'd like to get the letters in order, one at a time, like:

```
ἄ
β
α
ξ
```

I'm not really sure how to go about that, as the `.size` method reports a different length of the string than the ones we perceive. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work in 1.9

```
testStr="ἄβαξ"
testStr.each_char { |k|
        puts k
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby19

str = "ἄβαξ"
puts "#{str} - encoding: #{str.encoding.name} / size: #{str.size}"
str.each_char do |c|
  puts c
end
```

Using some Google-fu, you'll find a lot of [good articles](http://blog.nuclearsquid.com/writings/ruby-1-9-encodings) on Ruby 1.9 and character encoding.